# Convert key before invoking any function of map in C++

Tags: c++, std

I have a map as `map<string, T>`. Now I realized that the storing of strings is expensive in my memory and I want to store it as int. But I have called a lot of functions to this map passed as string.

E.g.

```
map<string, T> mp;
mp.find("123");
```

Is it anyhow possible that I change the type of my `map<string, T>` to `map<int, T>` and there I dont have to change functions like find anywhere else in the call, i.e. there is some intermediate method which can just convert the string to int ? I was thinking of doing inheritance but its a bad idea for c++ std as I read somewhere

Comment: If you are worried about using ```string```, why don't you use ```int``` since the beginning? Converting all the elements doesn't sound like a solution if performance is critical.

Comment: Can't you just go through your code and change all the string to int?

Comment: There are many, many ways to convert a string to an int. Starting with C library's `atoi()`, for example. Or C++'s `from_chars`. Not sure why you think inheritance has anything to do with anything, here.

Comment: Are the strings you're using for keys actually string representations of integers like `"123"` in your example, or are the keys arbitrary strings that you want to be able to represent as ints e.g. `"some_text"`?

Comment: code base is too large to make changes. can it be done more simply ?

Comment: @NathanPierson Just out of curiosity, is intermediate conversion possible ?

Comment: "Code base is too large" is not an option. If it has to be done, then change the whole code is a good idea, no matter how long. You can help yourself with regex to remove the quotes around the number.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to keep the old functions (the ones with string types) but trying to avoid the strings themselves, best case scenario, you'll add conversions and temporal `std::map<std::strings,>`. A workaround could be overloading the functions, so there will be only `std::map<std::strings,>` types on memory if you use them, hence you would be able to reduce the amount of strings (don't pay for what you don't use):

```
void foo(std::map<std::string, std::string>& m) {

    auto it = m.find("456");
    std::cout << std::distance(m.begin(), it) << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::map<int, std::string>& m) {

    auto it = m.find(456);
    std::cout << std::distance(m.begin(), it) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    m.insert({123,"bar"});
    m.insert({456,"bar"});    
    foo(m);
}
```